# JQuery CSS on html() text

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
var data = $("span", this).html(); /*grab all */
$calPopup.stop().fadeTo(300,1);
$calPopup.html(data);
```

I want to do something like:

```
data.css("font-size","10pt");
```

But if I do that, the html text doesn't even appear. Chrome's inspector says this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object *** has no method 'css'
```

How can I apply a CSS modification to the text?

Comment: You mix string with HTML and jQuery object. Try to read [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/) firstly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) jQuery function returns a String, not a jQuery object, so there's no `.css()` function to use. However, if you want to apply that CSS style to all of those `<span>` elements, it's as simple as calling your `.css()` function directly on the jQuery object that's selected them:

```
$('span', this).css('font-size', '10pt');
```

Note that I've removed the variable declaration because, based on the code provided, it seems unnecessary. Also note that the `.html()` function will return the HTML of the **first matched element** only, not all of them, so if you have more than one `<span>` element then you'll only get the HTML of the first.

To address edits to the question:

```
var data = $("span", this).clone().css('font-size', '10pt');
$calPopup.stop().fadeTo(300,1);
$calPopup.empty().append(data);
```

Comment: Can you see my updated code. I forget to put that I take the data and output it somewhere. How will your code change, if at all

Comment: @MichaelBenneton It would be easier to clone the `<span>` elements, call `.css()` on the cloned versions, then output that. I'll update my answer with code to do that.

Answer (score 1):

you're applying the `css()` method to the string returned by `html()` method and not to the element itself.

Do instead

```
var data = $("span", this).css("font-size","10pt").html();
```

or, even better, keep off style from javascript: just assign a class to your `span` element and let a css rule give the correct style

```
var data = $("span", this).addClass("yourclass").html();
```

CSS

```
.yourclass {
    font-size : 10pt;
}
```

Comment: this code looks perfectly correct but for some reason it just isn't working. Inspector isn't giving me any errors either. I know this is really broad, saying "isn't working", but any ideas?

Comment: please show us your attempts on a demo page / jsfiddle.net /jsbin.com example and update your question with a link

Answer (score 1):

The html() method will return the HTML text of the first matched element given in the selector. Here it returns just text and not jQuery Object

So better first find the jQuery Object and apply CSS

```
var data = $("span", this);
data.css("font-size","10pt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't apply the css on the html ...
You have to apply it on the span :

```
var data = $("span", this).css("font-size","10pt").html(); /*grab all */
```

Answer (score 0):

try wrapping data with $() to convert it to a jQuery object

```
$(data).css('font-size','10pt');
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to apply your formatting to the actual span element. .html() is getting the HTML in a string format, so .css won't work.

If you want to do .css on the whole span, simply change your variable to `var data = $("span", this);`