# Find Div and set CSS using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, html

my html is stored in a variable and i just find div from that variable and set css but things are not working. here is my code

```
sHtml = $(sHtml).find('#frm').html();
sHtml = $(sHtml).find('#acloginpod').css({ 'width': xWidth + 'px' });  
$sHtml = $(sHtml);
```

what is wrong in my 3rd line. i was try to find div **acloginpod** from html which is stored in sHtml variable and width is stored in xWidth variable. i thinks there is problem in my code but not being able to find it out. so please help me to rectify the code. thanks

Comment: What do you expect from your code?

Comment: Also can you post your html code ?

Comment: sHtml is a jquery selector , or some html value?

Comment: Do you know how to debug your javascript code? Finding out what `sHtml` is after the first line would be helpful.

Comment: xWidth is also undefined too, please explain exactly what you're after

Comment: There's many problems with your code. Where does `sHtml` come from and what are you going to do with it?

Comment: @ShannonHochkins I would also add that `xWidth` may be "NaN" if he calculates it.

Comment: you are mixing `sHtml ` as `string` and `object`.

Comment: You can refer existing post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12670063/jquery-css-on-html-text/12670113#12670113

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have included comments in your code:

```
sHtml = $(sHtml).find('#frm').html(); // Returns a string: the .innerHTML of the element with ID frm
sHtml = $(sHtml).find('#acloginpod').css({ 'width': xWidth + 'px' }); // Returns a jQuery object of the element with ID #acloginpod
$sHtml = $(sHtml); // No need to do that sHtml is already a jQuery object
```

Comment: Well, sHtml is indeed a jQuery object, but it's not the same as `$(sHtml)` - it's actually `$('#acloginpod')` in this series of statements.

Comment: @raina77ow an how does $(sHtml) change what was already stored in sHtml?

Comment: `$(sHtml)` doesn't change its value, of course. `sHtml = $(sHtml)` does, however.

Comment: @raina77ow If these two statements are sequential in the code, then the second one does nothing is what I meant :)
sHtml = $(sHtml).find('#acloginpod').css({ 'width': xWidth + 'px' });
$sHtml = $(sHtml);

Comment: What I meant is that second statement will not capture the whole element created from `sHtml` string, but only its part - the element with ID 'acloginpod'. And only this element will be stored in `sHtml`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're mixing HTML strings and DOM Objects (wrapped into jQuery objects) in your code.

With this line...

```
$(sHtml).find('#acloginpod').css({ 'width': xWidth + 'px' });
```

... you convert a string with HTML (sHtml) into a DOM object, then find some element within its hierarchy, then change its property.

But in this line...

```
$sHtml = $(sHtml);
```

... you're just throw all the changes away, as you *again* convert into a DOM object the original string.

I wonder why don't you just...

```
  $sHtml = $(sHtml);
  $sHtml.find('#acloginpod').css({ width: xWidth + 'px' });
```

... working (and transferring) with jQuery object all the time.